# Truffle test does nothing but compile work

Tags: solidity, truffle

I just started seeing solidity and truffle. I created a new project with the `truffle init` command and try this test code to verify the deployment of a contract.

```
const GreeterContract = artifacts.require("Greeter");

contract("Greeter", () => {       
  it("has been deployed successfully", async () => {
    const greeter = await GreeterContract.deployed();
    assert(greeter, "contract was not deployed");
  });
});
```

But the `truffle test` command does nothing and the terminal stands still as if waiting for something.
Instead `truffle compile` command works.

The anomaly occurs on both linux and windows. I also tried other test codes from the net or to write whatever, always the same result. Is it a bug?

Truffle version installed at the moment is the latest, 5.1.44

**EDIT**
This is the folder structure created by `truffle init`.The Greeter contract is missing to fail the test. However, I also tried to add it and nothing changes.

[image]

Comment: Put your Greeter.test.js file to the `test` folder. NOTE: Your example is missing a trailing curly brace.

Comment: The file is located in the test folder of the project (I updated the post with the structure that the init command created for me). The missing parenthesis was my distraction in the post.

Comment: If you try with an empty test folder does it work?

Comment: Did you try file name like `greeter.test.js`?

Comment: I get the same result both with empty test folder and renaming the file `greeter.test.js`.
I'm starting to think it's a problem on Ubuntu, Windows 10 and also with WSL2 because, not knowing what to do anymore, I try it on a PC with Fedora 32 and it works. It is really weird.

It is as if it does not understand the `test` command because if I write something wrong, like `tesst` I have the same problem, the terminal is waiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some time, I realized that the problem was the nodejs version. Truffle is incompatible with nodejs 14, I downgraded to nodejs 12 and it works on all operating systems.